# How many GH in 1 TH?

Tags: hashpower

Please tell me, is **1 TH = 1000GH**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct, one terahash (= 10^12 hashes) equals 1000 gigahashes (=1000*10^9 hashes).
Prefixes such as `tera`, `kilo`, or `milli` are *SI prefixes* (or *[metric prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix)*).

Or you can look at it in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+Terahash).